# Error: List Index out of Range Python

Tags: python

I have looked through all of the errors to find the solution, but I can't find a working solution!

I get List Index out of Range error.

"hand" and "deck" are both lists in this.

```
def draw(self,amount):
    for x in range(amount):
        print len(self.deck)
        if len(self.deck) == 0:
            self.shuffle
        else:
            pass
        self.hand.append(self.deck[0])
        self.deck.remove(self.deck[0])
```

I understand that it is giving the error because deck is just [] when the error passes. Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

Comment: It because one list of them (or both of them) is empty (or become empty while you're doing `self.deck.remove(self.deck[0])`). Can we see these lists?

Comment: Possibly provide the full code.

Comment: Need more information about hand & deck.

Comment: Sorry, when the error passes, hand is ['copper', 'copper', 'copper', 'copper', 'copper', 'copper', 'copper', 'estate', 'estate', 'estate'] and deck is []

Comment: If a list is empty, then you couldn't use `deck[0]`. It'll raise an error like you're getting because there's nothing in that list.

Comment: Added to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lacking more context I'm going to guess that you mean to be calling `self.shuffle()` and not `self.shuffle`.

Also, if deck is just a list you can replace the last two lines with:

```
self.hand.append(self.deck.pop(0))
```

Comment: Just fixed that (thanks!) but the error is still there. :(

Comment: We need more code to see what's going on. What does the implementation of `shuffle` look like?

Answer (score 0):

```
self.hand.append(self.deck[0])
```

If you deck is empty, this statement shouldn't be executed.  Unfortunately, it is not within the conditional if statement that you wrote for checking whether the deck is empty.

If you refactor it with that in mind, it should resolve the error for you.

Comment: Doesn't 
`if len(self.deck) == 0:
            self.shuffle`
execute if self.deck is zero though?

Comment: .shuffle will only move items into a random order within a collection.  If the collection contains nothing, then there's nothing to move.  The issue I see is self.deck[0] - if the List is empty, this statement cannot be processed (as there won't be an element at [0]